# Matching nested elements with different order and number format

Tags: java, .net, xml, xmlunit, xmlunit-2

I'm using [xmlunit 2.2.1](http://www.xmlunit.org/) with Java and have the following XMLs to match. The problem here is twofold:

1. the order is not the same
2. some of the numerical values may have trailing zeroes (e.g. `0.250000`)

For this reason `ByNameAndTextRecSelector()` doesn't work because it requires all the text nodes to be exact matches, which not the case here. I already implemented a `DifferenceEvaluator` that will take care of the trailing zeroes in the numbers. But what do I use to select the right elements to compare?

XML 1:

```
<test>
  <table>
    <row>
      <element>
        <code>ALPHA</code>
        <scale>0.25</scale>
      </element>
    </row>
    <row>
      <element>
        <code>DELTA</code>
        <scale>0.1</scale>
      </element>
    </row>
  </table>
</test>
```

XML 2:

```
<test>
  <table>
    <row>
      <element>
        <code>DELTA</code>
        <scale>0.1</scale>
      </element>
    </row>
    <row>
      <element>
        <code>ALPHA</code>
        <scale>0.2500000</scale>
      </element>
    </row>
  </table>
</test>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `code` element enough to select the correct nodes? If so, an approach like the user guide example https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/SelectingNodes#conditional-elementselectors should work.

```
ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
    .whenElementIsNamed("row").thenUse(ElementSelectors.byXPath("./element/code", ElementSelectors.byNameAndText))
    .elseUse(ElementSelectors.byName)
    .build();
```

This will not help against the different number formats. To deal with them you must override the `DifferenceEvaluator` and detect the `Text` nodes that hold numbers, parse them and mark the differences as `EQUAL` if they are close enough.

If `code` is not enough, then you will need to write an `ElementSelector` that takes care of the numbers like the `DifferenceEvaluator` I described above and combine that with `ElementSelectors.byNameAndText` inside the conditional above.

Comment: `code` is not enough, I will need `scale` too. How do I combine the two? Do I use `and` and put this inside the `thenUse`?

Comment: This seems to work:
`and(byXPath("./element/code", byNameAndText), byXPath("./element/scale", new SelectorByNameAndNumber()))`

Comment: `and` should have worked if you wanted to keep them separate as well. Glad it worked.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Btw, I don't use the `.elseUse` but instead I put the other `ElementSelector` as arguments in the constructor of `DefaultNodeMatcher`.

Comment: Could you please clarify your last comment? Does it make a difference if instead of using the `.elseUse` I put the other `ElementSelector` as argument in the constructor of `DefaultNodeMatcher`?

Comment: sorry, I completely misread your comment and overlooked the `and` but thought you had combined the selectors for `scale` and `code` into one.

Comment: When using the varargs version of `DefaultNodeMatcher`'s constructor you need to be careful about order. `byName` would match arbitrary `row`s in your case, so it had to come last or your custom selector was never called. Whether it works as well as `elseUse` depends on whether your custom selector would match non-`row` elements as well. If it doesn't, then the varargs constructor would yield the same result. If it might match non-`row` elements as well, you may get unintended results. I prefer to make things explicit with the `conditionalBuilder`, though.